# Smoothly animating google maps marker along a list of latlng points

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I am attempting to smoothly animate a google maps marker along a list of Latlng points with each point having its own time stamp. The issue I am running into is when I animate the marker along the list of points using an ObjectAnimator, the animation will smoothly animate between a pair of points but will abruptly stop before continuing on to animate between the next pair of points which creates multiple breaks in the overall animation. The following code is what I am using to animate the marker:

```
private void animateMarker(){
    final LatLngInterpolator linearLatLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator();

    //Create type evaluator to calculate latlng position based on elaspsed time and start and end values.
    TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {

            return linearLatLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        }
    };
    Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");


    final List<Animator> animations = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i < gpsIndices.size(); i++){
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
                marker, property, typeEvaluator, new LatLng(gpsPoints.get(gpsIndices.get(i)).getLatitude(), gpsPoints.get(gpsIndices.get(i)).getLongitude()));
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setDuration(duration);
        animation.setStartDelay(0);
        animations.add(animation);
    }

    AnimatorSet animator = new AnimatorSet();
    animator.setStartDelay(0);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.playSequentially(animations);
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: Log (and post) your `gpsIndices` values (just a sequential sample for 5-10 samples) - it may be the case that e.g. `gpsIndices.get[n] == gpsIndices.get[n+1]` for some cases - which means it would stay at these junctions for `duration`.  Trying different `duration`s would further demonstrate this.  Also can you post (or reference) your LatLngInterpolator implementation class ?  (I tried your code with my own `LatLngInterpolator` implementation and a simple list of points and could not reproduce your issue.)

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the suggestion. I printed all the gps values being used in the animation and it turns out I had multiple latlng points recorded twice so I was animating between two of the same latlng points which caused the break in the animations.